# How can I determine best fit for a time series decomposition?

Tags: r, time-series, goodness-of-fit, decomposition

I’m new to time series decomposition and have been doing Seasonal and Trend decomposition using Loess (STL) in R.

My data is reported monthly and it appears that seasonality is annual. From what I’m reading, I gather that the graph of the remainder can aid in determining fit.

What am I looking for in this graph? How can I improve fit? (Sorry if this is a stupid question.)

[image: time series decomposition results in R]

Comment: Do some of the answers to the question [Trend and Seasonal component fitting after decomposition of the time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291849/trend-and-seasonal-component-fitting-after-decomposition-of-the-time-series) answer your question?

Comment: @mhdadk Yes, thank you so much!